# Unwanted word breaks after inline mathjax formulae

Tags: markdown, mathjax

I'm using Mathjax to embed formulae in a Jekyll site, using Kramdown as my renderer.

It's working beautifully, *except* that an implicit word break is always inserted after an inline formula, which means that line wrapping can insert a line break between the formula and the punctuation. This leads to things like this:

```
Where this fell down was that my representation was very limited as to what
numbers it can represent. The _smallest_ number possible was the integer `1`,
which represented $$\frac{1}{64} \approx 0.016$$; the _largest_ number was
the integer `127` (the top bit is used for the sign), which represented $$1
\frac{63}{64} \approx 1.98$$.
```

...being rendered as this:

[image]

Which looks terrible.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The problem still exists in 2023...

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in way of working around this in MathJax nor in any markdown processor (that I'm aware of).

Two ways of approaching this:

1. move the punctuation inside the equation
2. add a post-processing heuristic somewhere in your toolchain that wraps equations surrounded by non-whitespace in an element whose styling includes`white-space: nowrap;`; this will ensure that no breaks appear within.

Comment: Regarding (2); any pointers as to whether such a thing exists?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a generic implementation. You could do this either after kramdown ran or after MathJax runs, depends on what you find easier. I vaguely remember an example coming up on the mathjax mailing lists; client-side it's always a bit heavy in DOM manipulations so I only know people who do it when rendering server-side. I might try cooking up a minimal example when I find the time.

Comment: Here's a quick hack to get started: https://codepen.io/pkra/pen/gKPjLP. The next step would be to check the preceding sibling as well (e.g., preceding opening parentheses). Synchronization with MathJax could also be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\(...\)` delimiters for in-line mathematics instead of `$$...$$` and wrap the whole (with ponctuation and no space) in a span tag works for me

```
Where this fell down was that my representation was very limited as to what
numbers it can represent. The _smallest_ number possible was the integer `1`,
which represented <span>\(\frac{1}{64} \approx 0.016\);</span> the _largest_ number was
the integer `127` (the top bit is used for the sign), which represented <span>\(1
\frac{63}{64} \approx 1.98\)..............</span>
```

Edit :
a snippet which illustrates the difference you may have between the two options (but once again, it will depend on your config)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

<span>\(1
\frac{63}{64} \approx 1.98\)..............................................................</span>
<br>(which works with no white-space:nowrap)
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">$$1
\frac{63}{64} \approx 1.98$$.............................................................</span>
<br>(which doesn't work with white-space:nowrap)
```

Comment: Given the screenshot, that's probably not the problem. The OP is probably using a markdown parser that uses `$$` for both inline and display (e.g. kramdown does this).

Comment: Both options are delimiters for mathjax ([inlineMath vs displayMath](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/preprocessors/tex2jax.html))  therefore, interpreted by mathjax, and depending on your config, it won't give the same result. But without knowing the OP's config, your are right, this is only guesswork

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yes, it's kramdown. I did attempt to say so but failed (typo in submission fixed).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Sorry, I didn't realize I was talking to God in person ! ;)

Comment: @scraaappy you are of course correct that `$$` are the defaults for block (and @dpvc is the real god anyway). It's just kramdown (and since then other pre-processors) that have made this unusual choice.

Comment: Sorry for not having understood OP's problem. I don't delete my (wrong) answer (might be helpful as a good example of misunderstanding?!;). I upvote your